# How do I enable multitouch on a Dell Inspiron 15R?

Tags: 11.10, dell, multi-touch, synaptics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable my synaptics trackpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81805/how-do-i-enable-my-synaptics-trackpad)

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on Dell Inspiron 15R, but the touchpad (manufactured by Alps) is recognized as a normal mouse, so it won't let me do multi-touch gestures such as scroll and zoom as Windows does.

I tried to install synaptics touchpad following this post: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad but it doesn't work for me. I copied the following from my installation process:

> shuoshen@shuoshen-Inspiron-N5110:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i
>   synaptics-dkms_1.1.1_all.deb  [sudo] password for shuoshen:  (Reading
>   database ... 164789 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to replace synaptics-dkms 1.1.1 (using
>   synaptics-dkms_1.1.1_all.deb) ...
>
> ------------------------------ Deleting module version: 1.1.1 completely from the DKMS tree.
>   ------------------------------ Done. Unpacking replacement synaptics-dkms ... Removing old module source... Setting up
>   synaptics-dkms (1.1.1) ... Loading new synaptics-1.1.1 DKMS files...
>
> Loading tarball for synaptics-1.1.1
>
> DKMS: ldtarball Completed.
>
> Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/synaptics/1.1.1/source ->
>                    /usr/src/synaptics-1.1.1
>
> DKMS: add Completed. Installing prebuilt kernel module binaries (if
>   any) Building module...
>
> Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
>
> Building module: cleaning build area..... make
>   KERNELRELEASE=3.0.0-12-generic -C /lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/build
>   SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/synaptics/1.1.1/build modules.....(bad exit
>   status: 2) ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for synaptics: 1.1.1
>   not found Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel:
>   3.0.0-12-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/synaptics/1.1.1/build/make.log for more information.
>   dpkg: error processing synaptics-dkms (--install):  subprocess
>   installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
>   Errors were encountered while processing:  synaptics-dkms

How can I enable multi-touch?