# How do I enable my synaptics trackpad?

Tags: 11.10, trackpad, synaptics

When I booted 11.10 from the Install CD, everything worked fine.

However, once I installed Ubuntu, my trackpad stopped working - does anyone know why this is so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## This is tested on Ubuntu 11.10, I don't seem to need it for 12.04.

## Note, this involved adding a third-party PPA - proceed with caution.

[More on the dangers of PPAs here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out/35636#35636)

First, make sure we're both experiencing the same problem. Run the following in a terminal:

`cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`

You should see something like the following:

> > Section "InputClass"
> >
> > ```
> >    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
> >
> >    Driver "synaptics"
> >
> >    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
> > ```

Now, you need to add the PPA - [for precise instructions on how to do that, take a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).

The PPA you need to add is `ppa:sergio91pt/synaptics+clickpads`

Now, update your system - run the following in the terminal:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

What that command does:

First part updates your system software list - this tells the computer where the software is that it needs to download.

The second part does the actual update of your system software.

Once that's done, reboot your computer - your trackpad should be working now.

After the reboot, you'll want to update/tweak your touchpad settings.

Head to `System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad`, and then switch to the touchpad tab, and you'll see something like this:

[image]

You can play around with those settings as much as you want, just so you can figure out what works best for you.

Comment: got a report like W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sergio91pt/synaptics+clickpads/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sergio91pt/synaptics+clickpads/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found

Comment: @Shyam I don't seem to need the PPA for 12.04, you might have another problem