# How do I enable a touchpad?

Tags: 11.10, touchpad

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 several months ago, but I haven't found a proper way to enable the touchpad.

I once tried something I can't recall the name.

Does any one have any suggestions?

Update:
Here's what `cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` shows:

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection
```

Comment: Does this work? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/81805/how-do-i-enable-my-synaptics-trackpad

Comment: @jrg Sorry, but seems not :( Is there a way to check if I did it right ?

Comment: Did you reboot your computer? The changes don't take affect until after that

Comment: @jrg Yes I did reboot, but it seems not working.

Comment: Do you actually have a synaptics trackpad? What does `cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` tell you?

Comment: @jrg I do have a synaptics one. Please see the updated post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2379/discussion-between-jrg-and-spirit-zhang), I have more questions to ask.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @jrg I think so.

Comment: What's the make and model of your computer? :)

Comment: @roadmrLenovo K43

Comment: Is this question still an issue or was the matter solved?

Answer (score -1):

Open the Software Center and search for *synaptics*, should have a couple of packages that after install should enable your touchpad.

I had the same problem on a Dell Inspiron 1545!

Comment: Can you give more detail about which software to install ? I searched for synaptics but only got three seemingly pointless packages.